# Explode PHP string by new line

Tags: php

Simple, right?  Well, this isn't working :-\

```
$skuList = explode('\n\r', $_POST['skuList']);
```

Comment: Single quotes mean "don't parse this string". @Select0r's answer is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove new lines and returns from php string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986299/how-to-remove-new-lines-and-returns-from-php-string) which already was a duplicate of [Reliably remove newslines from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274506/reliably-remove-newlines-from-string) and [some others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+newlines+from+string+php).

Comment: In addition to the single quotes issued mentioned by others, CRLF pairs are `\r\n` not the other way around.

Comment: Try to remember that: \R etur \N

Comment: $skuList = explode("\n\r", $_POST['skuList']);
should work. it really depends on how your string variable is wrapped up. could be " " or ' '    for $string = 'abc\n\rdef'  use   $skuList = explode('\n\r', $string);

Answer (score 558, accepted):

**Best Practice**

As mentioned in the comment to the first answer, the best practice is to use the PHP constant [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) which represents the current system's EOL (*End Of Line*).

```
$skuList = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['skuList']);
```

PHP provides a lot of other very [useful constants](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) that you can use to make your code system independent, see [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) to find useful and system independent directory constants.

**Warning**

These constants make your page system independent, but you might run into problems when moving from one system to another when you use the constants with data stored on another system. The new system's constants might be different from the previous system's and the stored data might not work anymore. So completely parse your data before storing it to remove any system dependent parts.

**UPDATE**

Andreas' comment made me realize that the 'Best Practice' solution I present here does not apply to the described use-case: the server's EOL (PHP) does not have anything to do with the EOL the browser (any OS) is using, but that (the browser) is where the string is coming from.

So please use the solution from [@Alin_Purcaru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3997367/1387233) to cover all your bases:

```
$skuList = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $_POST['skuList']);
```

Comment: You can't use PHP_EOL because the system and the input source have nothing to do with each other. If user put new lines in Windows and the PHP is running on Linux the result may be broken.

Comment: @barell exactly, thats the situation i describe in the 'warning' part ;) The question did not explicitly state that it is an old input stored in the database. Please read the 'warning' part and you will see that i cover that situation there.

Comment: This answer is just wrong for this use-case. Do not use the PHP_EOL constant in this case as the input source (e.g. the user's browser) is definitely not your system. Use a solution that takes care of all the different line endings (answer from Alin Purcaru).

Comment: So if I switch the server and the EOL PHP settings change, then I have a problem whenever I use this command for text from my database?

Comment: @Adam yes, you should normalize the strings that you store in your DB and always store them one way or the other, NOT with the systems EOL but one of the two. That way you won't have problems changing systems as all your strings in the DB have the same EOL string.

Comment: Below is a better, more flexible option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63922758/11977152

Answer (score 308):

Cover all cases. Don't rely that your input is coming from a Windows environment.

```
$skuList = preg_split("/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/", $_POST['skuList']);
```

or

```
$skuList = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $_POST['skuList']);
```

Comment: This will result in empty array elements if the eol is `\r\n`. To prevent that, either use: `preg_split('/\n|\r/', $_POST['skuList'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` (note that `\r\n` becomes unnecessary when using that flag) or simply put the `\r\n` *before* the `\r`: `preg_split('/\r\n|\n|\r/', $_POST['skuList']);`

Comment: @webbiedave PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY is nice, BUT it will delete empty lines. This may or may not be desirable.

Comment: This pattern would match every letter for me, because it results in success even if nothing is present. "?" means 0 or one time, so it is possible for it to match even if both \r and \n are not present.
You say "fixed" but I don't see that.
I used /(\r|\n)+/ instead.

Comment: @Rolf It seems I made an edit in a hurry. Corrected it now. What you should use depends on whether you want the empty lines or not in the output. The option from my answer also returns empty lines.

Comment: How about this?
`preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', $_POST['skuList']);`
(haven't tested it)
:)

Comment: @Rolf That one would not return the empty lines.

Comment: @AlinPurcaru Can you clarify in the answer which (both, either, neither?) will return blanks and which will not?

Comment: I think this answer should be used instead of the checked answer whenever your text comes from an database.

Comment: Your expression creates double lines for the (quite unusual) \n\r sequence. To cover that sequence as well, you can use `$skuList = preg_split('/\n\r|\r\n|\n|\r/', $_POST['skuList']);`

Comment: Demo: https://regexr.com/6ahvl (using N and R instead of \n and \r and using regexr.com, which is javascript engine).
This solution preserves line breaks (as blank items in the array)

Answer (score 161):

Try `"\n\r"` (double quotes) or just `"\n"`.

If you're not sure which type of EOL you have, run a str_replace before your explode, replacing "\n\r" with "\n".

Comment: Single quotes in PHP mean "don't parse this string". That means your control characters aren't being parsed, they're being taken as literal (not a line break and a carriage return, but actual, literal '\n\r'). Using double quotes means "parse this string", and thus your control characters will be parsed. +1

Comment: `/n/r`? I know the OP wrote that but the correct windows eol is `\r\n`

Comment: Consider the PHP *end of line* constant: `PHP_EOL`.

Comment: Hi everyone, this is definitely the right answer ! I'm wondering why did @Alin Purcaru answer got 44 votes.. It's wrong!!! It's not always working correctly although it seems that it does the job.. So here's my comment for anyone stucking on the same thing

Comment: Just disregard the \r, the last OS to use it without \n was OS9 ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations ). Therefore this will give you the best results: `explode("\n", str_replace("\r", '', $string));`

Answer (score 21):

It doesn't matter what your system uses as newlines if the content might be generated outside of the system.

I am amazed after receiving all of these answers, that no one has simply advised the use of the `\R` escape sequence.  There is only one way that I would ever consider implementing this in one of my own projects.  `\R` provides the most succinct and direct approach.

[https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php#:~:text=line%20break:%20matches%20\n,%20\r%20and%20\r\n](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php#:%7E:text=line%20break:%20matches%20%5Cn,%20%5Cr%20and%20%5Cr%5Cn)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ko1Jt))

```
$text = "one\ntwo\r\nthree\rfour\r\n\nfive";

var_export(preg_split('~\R~', $text));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'one',
  1 => 'two',
  2 => 'three',
  3 => 'four',
  4 => '',
  5 => 'five',
)
```

If you don't want empty elements in your output, then: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Gns7g)

- split on one or more newline sequences via regex engine

  ```
  var_export(preg_split('~\R+~', $text));  // may generate empty element at start and/or end of array
  ```
- remove elements with no length

  ```
  var_export(preg_split('~\R~', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
  ```
- **[BEST]** split on one or more newline sequences via regex engine AND remove elements with no length

  ```
  var_export(preg_split('~\R+~', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
  ```

---

As a consideration for scenarios where the input string may contain multibyte/unicode/accented/diacritic/non-latin characters, add the `u` pattern modifier to inform the regex engine to process the input string as multibute characters instead of individual bytes. `~\R+~u`

Comment: The best answer. People should see this, not just the first two answers :)

Comment: This type of regex breaks UTF strings, for example `ą` character is partially considered as newline.

Comment: @Grz, then add the `u` pattern modifier.  If this doesn't resolve a scenario that you can reproduce, please offer a 3v4l.org demo for me to observe the problem.

Comment: @mickmackusa You are right, the `'~\R~u'` modifier solves the case. The problem is hard to notice, as only few types of characters are impacted.

Answer (score 15):

Lots of things here:

- You need to use double quotes, not single quotes, otherwise the escaped characters won't be escaped.
- The normal sequence is `\r\n`, not `\n\r`.
- Depending on the source, you may just be getting `\n` without the `\r` (or even in unusual cases, possibly just the `\r`)

Given the last point, you may find `preg_split()` using all the possible variants will give you a more reliable way of splitting the data than `explode()`. But alternatively you could use `explode()` with just `\n`, and then use `trim()` to remove any `\r` characters that are left hanging around.

Answer (score 15):

try

```
explode(chr(10), $_POST['skuList']);
```

Answer (score 14):

this php function explode string by *newline*
**Attention** : new line in *Windows* is **\r\n** and in *Linux* and *Unix* is **\n**
this function change all new lines to *linux* mode then split it.
pay attention that empty lines will be ignored

```
function splitNewLine($text) {
    $code=preg_replace('/\n$/','',preg_replace('/^\n/','',preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/',"\n",$text)));
    return explode("\n",$code);
}
```

example

```
$a="\r\n\r\n\n\n\r\rsalam\r\nman khobam\rto chi\n\rche khabar\n\r\n\n\r\r\n\nbashe baba raftam\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";
print_r( splitNewLine($a) );
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => salam
    [1] => man khobam
    [2] => to chi
    [3] => che khabar
    [4] => bashe baba raftam
)
```

Comment: There is NO way that I would ever use your snippet.  The most direct / sensible technique for your invented string would be `var_export(preg_split('~\R+~', $a, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));`  Anything else is simply not clever. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Cv9KR)

Answer (score 9):

**To preserve line breaks** (as blank items in the array):

```php
$skuList = preg_split('/\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n/', $_POST['skuList']);`
```

This handles the unusual \n\r as well as the usual \n\r, \n and \r. Note that the solution from @Alin_Purcaru is very similar, but doesn't handle \n\r.

**To remove line breaks** (no blank items in the array):

```php
$skuList = preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', $_POST['skuList']);
```

**PHP Tests**
These expressions has been tested on the following OS'es: ubuntu-20.04, ubuntu-18.04, windows-2022, windows-2019, windows-2016, macos-11, macos-10.15 and in the following PHP versions: 8.0, 7.4, 7.3, 7.2, 7.1, 7.0

Here is the PHP test class:
https://github.com/rosell-dk/exec-with-fallback/blob/main/tests/LineSplittingTest.php

And a successful CI run on a project that runs those tests:
https://github.com/rosell-dk/exec-with-fallback/actions/runs/1520070091

**Javascript demos of the principle**
Here are some javascript demos of similar regular expressions (I'm using N and R instead of \n and \r).

Preserve linebreaks demo: https://regexr.com/6ahvl 
Remove linebreaks demo: https://regexr.com/6ai0j

PS: There is currently a bug in regexr which causes it to show "Error" when first loaded. Editing the expression makes the error go away

Answer (score 8):

For a new line, it's just

```
$list = explode("\n", $text);
```

For a new line and carriage return (as in Windows files), it's as you posted.  Is your skuList a text area?

Answer (score 8):

Place the `\n` in double quotes:

`explode("\n", $_POST['skuList']);`

In single quotes, if I'm not mistaken, this is treated as `\` and `n` separately.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using double quotes?

Answer (score 3):

Not perfect but I think it must be safest. Add [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php):

```
$skuList = explode('<br />', nl2br($_POST['skuList']));
```

Answer (score 3):

As easy as it seems

```
$skuList = explode('\\n', $_POST['skuList']);
```

You just need to pass the exact text **"\n"** and writing **\n** directly is being used as an Escape Sequence. So **"\\"** to pass a simple backward slash and then put **"n"**

Answer (score 1):

> `PHP_EOL` is ostensibly used to find the newline character in a cross-platform-compatible way, so it handles DOS/Unix issues.

Try this:

```
$myString = "Prepare yourself to be caught
You in the hood gettin' shot
We going throw hell of blows
got my whole frame froze";

$myArray = explode(PHP_EOL, $myString);

print_r($myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think it's usually `\r\n`, second of all, those are not the same on all systems. That will only work on windows. It's kind-of annoying trying to figure out how to replace new lines because different systems treat them differently (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)). You might have better luck with just `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Losing line breaks from posting from input textboxes?
What works faster for me is to copy paste any text or Excel or HTML table type or newline type of data and paste it into a textarea instead of an inputextbox:
this keeps the linebreaks intact in the POST.

```
 <textarea  id="txtArea" name="txtArea" rows="40" cols="170"></textarea>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="split lines into array" />
```

in the form receiving file:

```
 $txtArea ='';  
 $txtArea = $_POST['txtArea'];  
 $TA = $_POST['txtArea'];  
 $string = $TA;  
 $array = preg_split ('/$\R?^/m', $string); 
// or any of these: 
// $array = explode(PHP_EOL,$string);  
// $array = explode("\n", $txtArea); 
 echo "<br>A0: ".$array[0];
 echo "<br>A1: ".@$array[1];
 echo "<br>A2: ".@$array[2];
```

Comment: The anchors in this pattern  and the `?` are not necessary -- at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
explode(PHP_EOF, $lines);
```

Comment: Surely PHP_EOL rather than EOF

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. Tested in PHP 5.6 as well as as PHP 7.0:

```
    $skuList = str_replace("\\r\\n", "\n", $_POST['skuList']);
    $skuList = str_replace("\\n\\r", "\n", $skuList);

    $skuList = preg_split("/\n/", $skuList);
    print_r($skuList);
```

Answer (score -1):

This method always works for me:

```
$uniquepattern="@#$;?:~#abcz"//Any set of characters which you dont expect to be present in user input $_POST['skuList'] better use atleast 32 charecters.
$skuList=explode($uniquepattern,str_replace("\r","",str_replace("\n",$uniquepattern,$_POST['skuList'])));
```