# How to explode a string, with spaces and new lines?

Tags: php, delimiter

I would like to explode a string (separated based on a delimiter and placed into an array), using both a space (" ") and a newline ("\n") as a delimiter.

The method (which I don't think is the best way) is to:

1. Explode the array by spaces
2. Remake the string from the array
3. Explode it again for new lines
4. MySQL escape the individual elements.

**Question:** How do I exploded a string by both a space and new line?

Reference to: [new line Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997336/explode-php-string-by-new-line)

Comment: You can use regular expressions which is probably most efficient here. The other way is to explode twice, first by spaces and then each resulting array by new line character. At last, join all arrays into one (array_merge)

Comment: Use this : `preg_split('/[\s\n]/', $str );`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could just do a

```
$segments = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $string);
```

This function will split `$string` at every whitespace (`\s`) occurrence, including spaces, tabs and  newlines.  Multiple sequential white spaces will count as one (e.g. `"hello, \n\t  \n\nworld!"` will be split in `hello,` and `world!` only, without empty strings in the middle.

See function reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

Comment: I've been searching absolutely everywhere using preg_match, str_replace all sorts to find this perfect solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: It also removes multiple empty lines. Nice. No need to go over the resulting array and find empty slots.

Comment: great, but mind " a b " will give array of 4 elements: ["", "a", "b", ""]

Answer (score 7):

You can use `preg_split` to explode the content using multiple delimiter

```
$pattern = '/[ \n]/';
$string = "something here ; and there, oh,that's all!";
echo '<pre>', print_r( preg_split( $pattern, $string ), 1 ), '</pre>';
```

Comment: you should replace the `,` with `.` in your echo.

Comment: @TobiasKun It will not create any error. See its syntax `echo ( string $arg1 [, string $... ] )`

Comment: Although Tobias way is valid... it just hurts my eyes... changed it to be more readable to traditional folk like myself.

Answer (score 1):

Always go from the bigger to the smaller one.

So first split by `"\n"` and then split by `" "`.

```
$data = "This is a test\nAnd something new happens.";
$rows = explode("\n", $data);
$words = array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $temp = explode(" ", $row);
    foreach($temp as $word)
        $words[] = $word;
}
```

Will give you an array with all words in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use to explode the content using multiple delimiter.

Sample code

```
<?php
$str = "Brand : Pandora~ Collection : Summer 13~ Colour : Multi~ Gender : Ladies~ Material : Murano Glass~ Our Code : 0573835~ Packaging : Pandora Branded Packaging~ Product Code : 750513~ Product Type : Bead~ Style : Contemporary";
$r1 = explode("~", $str);
$stringtxt = '<table>';
if (count($r1) > 0) {
    foreach ($r1 as $value) {
        $rows = explode(":", $value);
        $stringtxt .= '<tr>';
        $stringtxt .= '<td>' . $rows[0] . '</td><td>' . $rows[1] . '</td>';
        $stringtxt .= '</tr>';
    }
}
$stringtxt .= '</table>';
print $stringtxt;
?>
```

Output

```
<table>
<tr><td>Brand </td><td> Pandora</td></tr>
<tr><td> Collection </td><td> Summer 13</td></tr>
<tr><td> Colour </td><td> Multi</td></tr>
<tr><td> Gender </td><td> Ladies</td></tr>
<tr><td> Material </td><td> Murano Glass</td></tr>
<tr><td> Our Code </td><td> 0573835</td></tr>
<tr><td> Packaging </td><td> Pandora Branded Packaging</td></tr>
<tr><td> Product Code </td><td> 750513</td></tr>
<tr><td> Product Type </td><td> Bead</td></tr>
<tr><td> Style </td><td> Contemporary</td></tr>
</table>
```