# Transfer into a PHP array the output of a Batch (.bat) file

Tags: php, batch-file, command-line, windows-console

I have this Batch file which looks for a string through the files contained in a folder.

```
@echo off
pushd "%1"
findstr /m /C:%2 *
popd
```

If I execute that from a command line, it prints the names of the files containing the searched string.

From PHP, the Batch file is being executed with this command:

```
system("cmd /c C:/path/myFile.bat C:/path toSearch", $returned);
```

The problem is that the `$returned` element is a string instead of an array.
Each of its elements is separted by a white space.

I was thinking of exploding it but it's not possible as some files contain also white spaces.

What is interesting is that in the source code of the page in which I print the resulting string each of the elements is in fact is one line, like so:

```
element1
second element
third element
```

But the resulting HTML code is this way:

```
element1 second element third element
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: so your delimiter is actualy `\n` as new line, instead of whitespace (don't know how much interesting is that HTML does not understand new lines, if they are not explicitly said by a tag, that breaks the line. So if there are not <br />, the web page will not break the lines)

Comment: I've tried to do expode it with the `"\n"` as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3997362/1081396) but It is not working so I'm not sure how it is actually separating the lines internally.

Comment: So what's the output when you explode on `\n` or `\n\r` ?

Comment: Ok, the problem is the use of `system`. I changed it for `exec` and now it is returning it in an array .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was that `system` automatically prints the output of the executed file.
I changed it for `exec` and now an array is being returned in the `$returned` variable.

```
exec("cmd /c C:/path/myFile.bat C:/path toSearch", $returned);
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru).