# Remove new line and carriage return characters in a string

Tags: php, preg-replace, newline, carriage-return

I'm trying to count the characters in a textarea, but it also counts "\n" and "\r" as characters; how would I remove them in order to count just the actual text input?

```
$pure_chars = preg_replace("/\r\n/", "", $_POST['comment']);
echo strlen($pure_chars);
```

Comment: New lines count toward the content length (ie they count as data). Just curious in what context spaces and punctuation would be relavent but newlines would not.

Comment: @Anthony Probably some do a return/enter as seperate lines, to make a new paragraph type of thing; least that's my take on it and that the OP doesn't want those to be counted.

Comment: The problem is it's counting a new line as 2 characters (I guess since it's "\n" plus "\r", as opposed to 1 (or maybe 0 would be better)

Comment: That makes more sense, but if there is a carriage return and line feed, it still uses data. What I'm wondering is what the character count is used for where you wouldn't count all characters. If its for setting a upper limit, the actual data will exceed the cleaned up count. If it's to determine word count or similar, than you should also account for spaces and punctuation. If you are trying to conserve space, you want to normalize or remove the characters, not get a count without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pure_chars = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/','', $string)
```

Note that you're still counting spaces, punctuation, etc, so it's really a matter of deciding what you really want to count. If you want to exclude anything that isn't a letter or a digit, use `/\W/`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all vertical whitespaces with `\v` or all sequences of newlines (regardless of operating system) with [the `\R` metacharacter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) which matches `\n`, `\r` and `\r\n`.

I recommend using the "one or more" quanitifier `+` so that longer potential matches are made and therefore fewer potential replacements.

```
$pure_chars = preg_replace('/\v+/', '', $_POST['comment']);
```

or

```
$pure_chars = preg_replace('/\R+/', '', $_POST['comment']);
```

<sub>Here is [a popular demonstration of \R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63922758/2943403).</sub>