# Convert text to array at key word

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I'm trying to get a block of text to an array in PHP dividing the text up at key words, in this case **Option *n*:**, where *n* is any character or number. Here is a sample text:

## Example input

```
OPTION A: Lorem ipsum dolar sit
Ut mattis velit nec tortor congue gravida. Duis leo arcu, maximus vel convallis vitae, laoreet in metus. Duis nec nisl id eros tincidunt dignissim. Sed condimentum commodo mi, a tristique risus vehicula ut. Sed eget ultrices lacus. Curabitur sed eleifend sapien, nec pharetra nunc.
Note: This option requires Option K-1: Extended Drill Depth. Nunc eu est bibendum nibh ullamcorper fermentum eget ut ante. Cras sed eros ac odio congue auctor. Nunc vel euismod neque.

OPTION D: Quisque efficitur
Morbi elementum metus posuere congue scelerisque. Vestibulum blandit pulvinar leo sit amet ornare. Maecenas porttitor lectus augue, et scelerisque nisl imperdiet non. Curabitur vel ligula sit amet leo auctor malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin facilisis erat ipsum, ut sagittis velit aliquam a. Nulla nulla orci, dapibus at ullamcorper suscipit, aliquam vel nisl. Duis eu libero ut leo ornare tempor. Donec egestas ipsum nec augue pellentesque aliquet.

OPTION G: Duis leo arcu
Aenean porttitor nulla eu eleifend hendrerit. Duis sed pretium nunc, sed semper leo. Nam sit amet quam semper, tempor risus vitae, consequat ex. Quisque ut rutrum enim, aliquet sodales justo. Morbi fringilla ac justo vitae molestie. Donec in molestie mauris, a scelerisque dolor.
Note: Nunc eu est bibendum nibh ullamcorper fermentum eget ut ante. Cras sed eros ac odio congue auctor. Nunc vel euismod neque.

OPTION IL: Fusce fermentum
Donec sed sagittis purus. Aliquam auctor nibh a varius sagittis. Nullam eget nulla orci. Nam eu dolor posuere, semper dui vitae, mattis leo. Vestibulum vitae dolor fringilla, gravida nulla ac, malesuada urna.

OPTION O: Morbi elementum
Nunc mi nisi, tempus non finibus nec, vulputate quis augue. Sed bibendum, dui nec venenatis efficitur, turpis libero efficitur odio, ac mollis est ex ut arcu. Aenean congue a metus quis euismod. Etiam at dui urna. Duis elementum, sapien ac volutpat mollis, augue neque pellentesque arcu, at finibus ligula nulla et libero. Curabitur vel mauris tortor. Mauris suscipit neque ac mauris lacinia tristique. Quisque faucibus semper lectus, eu ultricies sapien ultrices nec.
```

## Desired output

Ideally I'd like the above sample to look like this:

```
array:15 [▼
  0 => "OPTION A: Lorem ipsum dolar sit
        \n
        Ut mattis velit nec tortor congue gravida. Duis leo arcu, maximus vel convallis vitae, laoreet in metus. Duis nec nisl id eros tincidunt dignissim. Sed condimentum commodo mi, a ristique risus vehicula ut. Sed eget ultrices lacus. Curabitur sed eleifend sapien, nec pharetra nunc. \r\n
        Note: Nunc eu est bibendum nibh ullamcorper fermentum eget ut ante. Cras sed eros ac odio congue auctor. Nunc vel euismod neque."
  1 => "OPTION D: Quisque efficitur
        \n
        Morbi elementum metus posuere congue scelerisque. Vestibulum blandit pulvinar leo sit amet ornare. Maecenas porttitor lectus augue, et scelerisque nisl imperdiet non. Curabitur vel ligula sit amet leo auctor malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin facilisis erat ipsum, ut sagittis velit aliquam a. Nulla nulla orci, dapibus at ullamcorper suscipit, aliquam vel nisl. Duis eu libero ut leo ornare tempor. Donec egestas ipsum nec augue pellentesque aliquet."
  2 => "OPTION G: Duis leo arcu
        \n
        Aenean porttitor nulla eu eleifend hendrerit. Duis sed pretium nunc, sed semper leo. Nam sit amet quam semper, tempor risus vitae, consequat ex. Quisque ut rutrum enim, aliquet sodales justo. Morbi fringilla ac justo vitae molestie. Donec in molestie mauris, a scelerisque dolor. \r\n
        Note: Nunc eu est bibendum nibh ullamcorper fermentum eget ut ante. Cras sed eros ac odio congue auctor. Nunc vel euismod neque."

  3 = > ...
  4 => ...
  etc.
]
```

Alternatively using the **Option *n*:** text as the array key and the description as the value would be elegant as well, but I have no idea how to accomplish this.

## Using `preg_split()`

I have been trying to use `preg_split()` with little success, my current progress is here:

```
preg_split('/(Option [\w]+: \s*([^\r\n]*))/', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Which outputs:

```
array:15 [▼
  0 => "OPTION A: Lorem ipsum dolar sit"
  1 => "Lorem ipsum dolar sit"
  2 => """
    \r\n
    Ut mattis velit nec tortor congue gravida. Duis leo arcu, maximus vel convallis vitae, laoreet in metus. Duis nec nisl id eros tincidunt dignissim. Sed condimentum commodo mi, a ristique risus vehicula ut. Sed eget ultrices lacus. Curabitur sed eleifend sapien, nec pharetra nunc. \r\n
    Note: Nunc eu est bibendum nibh ullamcorper fermentum eget ut ante. Cras sed eros ac odio congue auctor. Nunc vel euismod neque.\r\n
    """
  3 => "OPTION D: Quisque efficitur"
  4 => "Quisque efficitur"
  5 => """
    \r\n
    Morbi elementum metus posuere congue scelerisque. Vestibulum blandit pulvinar leo sit amet ornare. Maecenas porttitor lectus augue, et scelerisque nisl imperdiet non. Curabitur vel ligula sit amet leo auctor malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin facilisis erat ipsum, ut sagittis velit aliquam a. Nulla nulla orci, dapibus at ullamcorper suscipit, aliquam vel nisl. Duis eu libero ut leo ornare tempor. Donec egestas ipsum nec augue pellentesque aliquet.\r\n
    """
  6 => "OPTION G: Duis leo arcu"
  7 => "Duis leo arcu"
  8 => """
    \r\n
    Aenean porttitor nulla eu eleifend hendrerit. Duis sed pretium nunc, sed semper leo. Nam sit amet quam semper, tempor risus vitae, consequat ex. Quisque ut rutrum enim, aliquet sodales justo. Morbi fringilla ac justo vitae molestie. Donec in molestie mauris, a scelerisque dolor. \r\n
    Note: Nunc eu est bibendum nibh ullamcorper fermentum eget ut ante. Cras sed eros ac odio congue auctor. Nunc vel euismod neque.\r\n
    """
  9 => "OPTION IL: Fusce fermentum"
  10 => "Fusce fermentum"
  11 => """
    \r\n
    Donec sed sagittis purus. Aliquam auctor nibh a varius sagittis. Nullam eget nulla orci. Nam eu dolor posuere, semper dui vitae, mattis leo. Vestibulum vitae dolor fringilla, gravida nulla ac, malesuada urna.\r\n
    """
  12 => "OPTION O: Morbi elementum"
  13 => "Morbi elementum"
  14 => """
    \r\n
    Nunc mi nisi, tempus non finibus nec, vulputate quis augue. Sed bibendum, dui nec venenatis efficitur, turpis libero efficitur odio, ac mollis est ex ut arcu. Aenean congue a metus quis euismod. Etiam at dui urna. Duis elementum, sapien ac volutpat mollis, augue neque pellentesque arcu, at finibus ligula nulla et libero. Curabitur vel mauris tortor. Mauris suscipit neque ac mauris lacinia tristique. Quisque faucibus semper lectus, eu ultricies sapien ultrices nec.
    """
]
```

As you can see for some reason it is duplicating the line immediately following the keywords as well as splitting the description text into its own entry.

My question is this: is there a better/more reliable method to accomplish this outside of `preg_split()`, e.g., `substr` in combination with other methods? If not how can I fix my logic to accomplish my goal?

## Update with working solution

Thanks to @RomanPerekhrest I am using the following code to generate the desired array: `preg_match_all("/\n?OPTION [\w:]+:.+?(?=\nOPTION\s|$)/s", $input, $outputArray);`

There was an issue where if an option was referenced in the body of the description it would delete the rest of the line from that point on. The solution was to alter the regexp from this:

`"/OPTION [^:]+:.+?(?=\n?OPTION\s|$)/s"`

To this:

`"/\n?OPTION [\w:]+:.+?(?=\nOPTION\s|$)/s"`

I am still very new to regex but if I understand correctly the removal of the `?` after the new line constraint makes the new line a requirement rather than optional, therefore the options will only ever be put into the array as a new key if they are on a new line, or are the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using `preg_match_all` function:

```
// $text is your input text
preg_match_all("/OPTION [^:]+:.+?(?=\n?OPTION\s|$)/s", $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);  // now $matches[0] contains the array of needed items
```

`/s` modifier. *If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines*

`(?=...)` - *positive lookahead assertion*. Matches the current OPTION content if it's followed by next OPTION or it's the last OPTION in the list(`\n?OPTION\s|$`)

[DEMO link](https://eval.in/618672)

Comment: I am currently using this solution and it is working almost exactly as desired, however I noticed that in some option descriptions people will reference other options, e.g., "Note: Requires Option K-1 ...", and that is being put into its own array key. How do I make it only choose options that have no preceding text on the same line, but ignores options that do?

Comment: @gmask, can you update your *example input* with that new condition?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have updated the question but I think I also found the solution, which I added to the end. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

How to do it with a lookahead assertion (as @Casimir pointed out):

```
array_filter(preg_split('~(?m)(?=^OPTION)~', $input), 'trim');
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you can just use explode to split on the blank lines. Try something like this:

```
$pieces = explode("\n\n", $input);
```

Here is an example: https://repl.it/CkBl/0

Comment: Unfortunately the input text will vary greatly here depending on who input the text: some entries have no new lines at all, merely a list of "Option n: <description>"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to split string on line break.

```
explode("\n", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your text at the zero or more newline characters which occur before the word `OPTION` at the start of any line.  The `m` pattern modifier tells the regex engine that `^` means the start of any line instead of the start of the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Zf6qM))

```
var_export(
    preg_split('/\R*^(?=OPTION)/m', $text, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

<sub>Here is [a post that describes `\R`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77575000/2943403)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

It's splitting on every capture, even the nested one.  So `([^\r\n]*)` will create separate elements in the resulting array.  Based on your example data you could simply split on two or more newlines to have the whole block of text in each array element:

```
preg_split('/[\r\n]{2,}/', $input);
```

Or if you want to rely on the `OPTION` string instead, grab the whole block of text and then trim it of newlines after:

```
$result = preg_split('/(OPTION [\w]+:.*)/', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
// Remove trailing newlines
$result = array_map('trim', $result);
```

Comment: This answer simply doesn't work `.*` makes the script explode too often. https://3v4l.org/toiep  Furthermore, `[\w]` is more simply written as `\w`.