# How php to open, read, transfer to mysql database very line by line content

Tags: php, html, sql

I have read some posts where a php file opens and writes the info to a database ,but it has a delimiter such as `|` or `,` or `..` or `' '`

However, I have a txt file that deals with numbers and the delimiter is not present in  numbers. **But i want to store that huge numbers depend upon there description.**

**That Description of number store in different column of the mysql database line by line**

For example :

```
34012015000220001000631931058620000607262Y22122014 N                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
34012015000220002000637717660206000607262Y23122014 N                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
34012015000220003000647245251009000607262Y23122014 N
```

Here is 34 is constant value.

```
        012015000220001-record No.
        000631931058620-Aadhar No.
        000607262-BIN no.
        Y-record status
        22122014-date
         -one blank space
        N-Mapping Status
```

Each new line is a new customer with their `individual details`.

So please sir give me any `solution` to solve this problem?

Comment: do you have same length on numbers or length can change?

Comment: Maybe this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997336/explode-php-string-by-new-line

Comment: PHP substr() might be your fried: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this, If you have same length of numbers.

```
$string = "34012015000220001000631931058620000607262Y22122014 N";
$constant = substr($string, 0, 2);
$record_no = substr($string, 2, 18);
$Aadhar = substr($string, 17, 14); // and so on...
print_r($Aadhar);
```

Comment: But the File has huge contents which is large no of line in this text file .So i want to store each line depend upon there decription ( i.e. constant,record no,aadhar no etc.) store in the database which insert the whole text file data line by line.

Comment: But the File has huge contents which is large no of line in this text file .So i want to store each line depend upon there decription ( i.e. constant,record no,aadhar no etc.) store in the database which insert the whole text file data line by line.It means every line in text file which store in database in each line.

Answer (score 0):

You may split each line by [unpack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) or [sscanf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) function

**example1**

```
$line = '34012015000220001000631931058620000607262Y22122014 N';
$fields = sscanf($line, '%2s%15s%15s%9s%1s%8s %1s');
print_r($fields);
```

it prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 34
    [1] => 012015000220001
    [2] => 000631931058620
    [3] => 000607262
    [4] => Y
    [5] => 22122014
    [6] => N
)
```

**example2**

```
$line = '34012015000220001000631931058620000607262Y22122014 N';
$fields = unpack('A2const/A15recordNo/A15aadharNo/A9binNo/A1date/A8date/A1/A1mappingStatus', $line);
print_r($fields);
```

it prints:

```
Array
(
    [const] => 34
    [recordNo] => 012015000220001
    [aadharNo] => 000631931058620
    [binNo] => 000607262
    [date] => 22122014
    [1] => 
    [mappingStatus] => N
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, shoot the person who designed the text file.

Secondly, parse it using a simple `substr()` assuming that each field is of constant length:

```
// create your sql, prepare it, bind it 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %sn", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Prepare an insert statement */
$query = "INSERT INTO table (rec, aadhar, ...) VALUES (?,?,...)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss...", $recno, $aadhar, ...);

while ($ln = fgets($fh)) {
    $recno = substr($ln, 0, 20);
    $aadhar= substr($ln, 21, 12);
    ...
    /* Execute the statement */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}

/* close statement */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

SOURCE: Example modified from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php