# How to get a new line from peragraph using preg_match_all function in php?

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a peragraph with some new lines :

```
 First line

Second line

Third line

 And this is the last line
```

I want to get the second line from the above peragraph.

So the result I want should be :

```
 "Second line"
```

I have tried the following script with **preg_match_all()** function but I don't know why it's not working.

```
 <?php
 $pera="First line

 Second line

 Third line

  And this is the last line";


 preg_match_all("#\n+{2}.*+#",$pera,$results);
print_r($results);
```

Do you have any idea how to get the second line from the paragraph?

Any help is much appriciated.

Thanks!

Comment: try `explode` .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997336/explode-php-string-by-new-line

Comment: `$array = array_values(array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $pera)));` <- Then just do: `echo $arr[1];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only for the purpose demonstrated, `explode` is really better for performance, but if you do want/have to use regex, don't use `preg_match_all`. That makes it global but you don't need that so go with `preg_match`. Then, change the pattern:

```
\n{2}.*
```

This will match the second line including leading newline character.

https://regex101.com/r/jA3dL9/1

If you want to match w/o the newline, use a capturing group:

```
\n{2}(.*)
```

Comment: You should change `.*` to `.+` in case there are three consecutive newlines and `\n` to `\R` to handle any kind of newline sequence whatever the OS.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$pera="First line

 Second line

 Third line

 And this is the last line";


$results = explode("\n", $pera);
print_r($results[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$data = array_values(
    array_filter(
        explode("\r\n", $pera) // or just \n
    )
);

echo $data[1]; // n°line - 1
```

Demo: http://3v4l.org/gpgOj

Comment: Newlines under Windows are `\r\n` not `\n\r`