# Coloring the echo output in php

Tags: php

I am reading a textile in php which has two sentences.

Top 1: 201 The Secret

Top 4 : 203, 290, 593, 224

What a Life!, Magical, Unicorn Land, Fire

```
function getcontent($file1){
    $fh= fopen($file1, 'r');
    $theData = fread($fh, filesize("$file1"));
    return $theData;
    fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

I wish to highlight the 2 sentences in different colors when I echo the file:

```
<div align="center"><h4 style="line-height:150%;"><?php echo "<pre>"  .$movies. "</pre>"; ?></h5></div>
```

$movies is the textfile. How can I do so in php? Would I have to create a separate function for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function is a simpler way to get your file's contents.

If your file only ever has 2 lines, there may be a simpler way to do this, but you could split the lines via [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) (for details on exploding text that might have strange line breaks, [try here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997336/explode-php-string-by-new-line)), which would look something like this:

```
$movies = file_get_contents("filename.txt");
$lines = explode("\n", $movies);
```

Then loop through the lines and style as desired:

```
if (is_array($lines)) {
    $line_count = count($lines);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $line_count; $i++) {
        if ($i % 2 == 0) {
            echo '<span style="color: red;">' . $lines[$i] . '</span><br>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<span style="color: blue;">' . $lines[$i] . '</span><br>';
        }
    }
}
```

More detailed logic could be implemented to color lines differently if there are more than 2 lines in the file.

Per your comment, the following code will color the first line red, and all other lines blue:

```
if (is_array($lines)) {
    $line_count = count($lines);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $line_count; $i++) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            echo '<span style="color: red;">' . $lines[$i] . '</span><br>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<span style="color: blue;">' . $lines[$i] . '</span><br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, its technically 3 lines actually, I meant Top 1 is one sentence and top 4 labels along with the names are the second sentence(combined). So currently, the code returns the first 2 lines in red and the names in blue. If i want the top 1 in red and top 4 along with the topic in blue, how can I do so?

Comment: See my edit above that addresses your specific need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array to store the different sentences, so the new code would be something like this. By the way, code after a return statement is never executed, so avoid that

```php
function getcontent($file1)
{
    $lines = file($file); //read all lines to array
    return $lines;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
    <h4 style="line-height:150%;">
        <?php
            //lines is the array returned from getcontent
            foreach($lines as $line)
            {
                echo "<pre>"  .$line. "</pre>"
            }
         ?>
    </h5>
</div>
```

After that you could use an if-clause to swap colors so each row has an alternating color, or a random color if you'd like that

Comment: foreach($lines as $line){
echo '<span style="color:#AFA;text-align:center;"> "<pre>"  .$line. "</pre>"</span>';}

I tried this but I think the html, php and <pre> are resulting in no output.