# Cut String after word wrap

Tags: php, string

I get a long string and want to cut them into an array like this:

```
"'1': '-'
 '2': CompanyA; 100EUR/Std
 '3': Company2; 100EUR/Std
 '4': Company B ; 155EUR/Std"
```

to:

```
array(
 1 => '-',
 2 => 'CompanyA; 100EUR/Std',
 3 => 'Company2; 100EUR/Std',
 4 => 'Company B ; 155EUR/Std'
);
```

Is it possible to cut a String after a word wrap?

Comment: Are the `'1:'` used as keys or is it just regular keys? And have you tried something?

Comment: The first value of array is correct or it is a typo (you maintain it after the key contrary to other) ?

Comment: when creating a new indexed array, the first key will start at `0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explode PHP string by new line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997336/explode-php-string-by-new-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a regular expression pattern for this:

```
$pattern =
"
    ~       
    ^       # start of line
    '       # apostrophe
    (\d+)   # 1st group: one-or-more digits
    ':\s+   # apostrophe followed by one-or-more spaces
    (.+)    # 2nd group: any character, one-or-more 
    $       # end of line
    ~mx
";
```

Then, with `preg_match_all`, you will obtain all the keys in group 1 and the values in group 2:

```
preg_match_all( $pattern, $string, $matches );
```

At the end, use `array_combine` to set desired keys and values:

```
$result = array_combine( $matches[1], $matches[2] );
print_r( $result );
```

will print:

```
Array
(
    [1] => '-'
    [2] => CompanyA; 100EUR/Std
    [3] => Company2; 100EUR/Std
    [4] => Company B ; 155EUR/Std
)
```

<kbd>**[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/aQ4zU7/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$string = "'1': '-'
 '2': CompanyA; 100EUR/Std
 '3': Company2; 100EUR/Std
 '4': Company B ; 155EUR/Std"

$a = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);

foreach ($a as $result) {
    $b = explode(':', $result);
    $array[$b[0]] = $b[1];
}

print_r($array);
```

hope it helps :)