# I am making a keyword tool in (PHP) and I want to separate the textarea input into sentences which are input in the textarea line by line

Tags: php

I thought of using **explode function** but it does not separate on the basis of sentences and I want to separate the input into sentences.

**The TEXT does not contain full-stop So using it for separating is out of question**

Comment: Is there any reliable delimiter between sentences besides a full stop?  a tab? a new-line?

Comment: good.Just read it :- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes there is new line after every sentence

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you need to explode value by new line character. Please try

$array = explode(PHP_EOL, );

$array = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', );

Please check this answer. [Explode PHP string by new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997336/explode-php-string-by-new-line)