# Exploding CSV file on new line

Tags: php, csv

I'm attempting to build a CSV parser in PHP. Unfortunately I'm unable to use fgetcsv so I'm building a custom function.

I have the contents of the csv held in a string, I'm attempting to explode the string on the new line character but I'm having difficulties with this.

```
$array_of_lines = explode(PHP_EOL,$csv_string);
```

This doesn't work, neither does exploding on "\n", could any suggest what character I might need to explode on?

Comment: try `\r` or `\r\n`

Comment: Show us the string or at least some of it

Comment: Where does the original data come from Unix or Windows and where are you running the script Unix or Windows

Comment: @RiggsFolly `PHP_EOL` works for both Linux and Windows.

Comment: @HenryA. Yea I nearly made that mistake! My point is if code is running on Windows `PHP_EOL` will be `\n` and if the data came from Unix the newlines in the file will be `\r\n` therefore there may be a mismatch

Comment: @HenryA. See the **Warning** in the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997336/explode-php-string-by-new-line

Comment: @RiggsFolly. CSV files should *not* be simply split on every newline, as fields can contain linebreaks. That means that this is not a duplicate and should not have been closed.