# php - unable to split a string by new lines from database

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, split

I'm receiving data from a MSSQL database with PHP (using PDO sqlsrv driver).

I need to split the string by new line.

In the DB the string looks like this:

[image: the string in the database]

I tried the following with no success:

```
$text = explode("\n\n",$text);
$text = preg_split("/\n\n/",$text);
```

Or

```
$text = explode("\n",$text);
$text = preg_split("/\n/",$text);
```

When i debug the code and when i print the text to the browser the string appears as one line.

[image: text echoed to the broswer]

But if i inspect the element in chrome, it is displayed exactly like in the database:

[image: text inspected with chrome]

I copied the text from the inspector to a regex tester and the newlines were found successfully! But the "echoed" text was in one line.

Comment: look at your HTML source, I'm sure the breaks are in there. Use `nl2br()` for screen output, or `<br>`'s.

Comment: which way you insert this string in database? did you add new line? or br tag?

Comment: @Fred-ii- well nl2br() actually adds <br> in the correct places, but then i need to try and split the string with <br> which is kinda messy...

Comment: @shashikant The data is entered through a SAP program, its a regular windows editor (non html) a my guess is that they just insert a new line

Comment: There is just one way you can explode data by dot.

Comment: I don't know how else you're going to get away with this, and why do you feel that `<br>'` are messy? If you want clean HTML, use `\n` and `<br>`. See the answer below then, I don't know how else to help here, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing new line character with comma (,) or something other special char.

```
preg_replace("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", ',', $input);
```

Then try to explode like this `explode(',', $input);`

or 
if result set is file go through this post

```
explode(PHP_EOL, $input);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29471912/4895810

Comment: Thanks, ended up using this method.
Whats wierd that that  `preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $text);` just didn't work! Oh well...