# how to send email to multiple recipients using textarea box?

Tags: php, email

I send email to multiple recipients using below code but its has problem. First i have to set all emails on php code ($to="email,email,email more"). Then i can send them email.

I wants a text area box () for paste my all email/email list and send them.
I don't want to add email one by one on php code.

This is my Code:

```
<?php
     $to = $_POST['email_list']; //i'm trying this but not working.
     //$to = "xyz@somedomain.com".","."xyz1@somedomain.com".","."xyz2@somedomain.com";
     $subject = $_POST['subject'];
     $message = $_POST['message']; 
     $header = "From:abc@somedomain.com \r\n";
     $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
     if( $retval == true ) {
        echo "Message sent successfully...";
     }else {
        echo "Message could not be sent...";
     }
  ?>
  <textarea type="text" name="email_list"></textarea><br/>
  <input type="text" name="subject"/><br/>
  <textarea type="text" name="message"></textarea><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: Try to paste comma separated emails in the text area.

Comment: thanks, using comma its working but i don't use comma on textarea, i wants to add only emails

Comment: i have to use like this: `$_POST['email_list'].',';`

Comment: There should be some delimiter to get multiple emails from text area.

Comment: so what i need to change on code?

Comment: If you want to add multiple emails in the textarea, add them either using delimiter or one email for each line. Then change the code in php to read multiple emails and implode them with comma.

Comment: You have too many questions with nothing marked as solutions. This doesn't help the system to let it know that solutions were given and no further answer need be given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build a list of email recipients, you can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get the list of emails into an array, and then use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to get them into a single string with a comma delimiter.

For example, if you have a textarea with an email address seperated with a new line character (one email per line), you can use PHP's [`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) as the delimiter.

```
// Get the submited email addresses into an array
$email_list = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['email_list']);
// Implode that array into a comma-delimited string
$to = implode(",", $email_list);
```

If need be, you could run `$email_list` through a `foreach` loop or `array_walk` first, if you want to validate the email addresses, etc.

**Edit**: See this answer: [Explode PHP string by new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997336/explode-php-string-by-new-line/3997367#3997367).
Rather than relying on PHP_EOL, it may be best to use a regular expression to look for \r and \n. Reason being that EOL is system (server) dependent, while the actual line break character(s) come from the end user's browser, which uses *their* operating system's EOL.

Comment: And if you want to use any delimiter other than comma, use $email_list = explode(delimiter, $_POST['email_list']);

Comment: can you please update full code

Comment: i am trying like this: `$to = explode(EOL, $_POST['email_list']);` and `$recipients = implode(",", $to);` but not working. i wants to add email on textarea box without comma.

Comment: @MasudRana I updated the answer to show that you assign the returned string from `implode()` to your `$to` variable. You've almost got it, except it's backwards. The implode() result is what you want for your `$to`.

Comment: its showing me notice: `Notice: Use of undefined constant EOL - assumed 'EOL'`

Comment: @MasudRana It's `PHP_EOL`.

Comment: @MasudRana That was my mistake.  It should have been `PHP_EOL`, instead of `EOL` as the explode() delimiter.  However, after reviewing what PHP_EOL covers, explode() may not be the best case here. Rather, you should use preg_split, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3997367/4458445), if you want to separate your email addresses by line.  I can update the answer to use preg_split if you intend to use "one email per line".

Comment: Its working, thanks @RToyota sir and barmar sir