# convert a php string to php array based on a character

Tags: php, arrays

This is my php string --

```
Advertiser ID\tCompany\tManager\tContact Person\tIM_Skype
```

Now need to convert it to array based on "\t".

how to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explode PHP string by new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997336/explode-php-string-by-new-line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***1.*** In case of string have single-quote then using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
<?php

    $string = 'Advertiser ID\tCompany\tManager\tContact Person\tIM_Skype';
    $array = explode('\t',$string);
    print_r($array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/990122

***2.*** In case of string have double-quote then

```
<?php

    $string = "Advertiser ID\tCompany\tManager\tContact Person\tIM_Skype";
    $array = explode("\t",$string);
    print_r($array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/990131