# cannot explode a string by new lines from a txt file

Tags: php, explode

cannot explode a string by new lines from a `txt` file

**colors.txt**

```
rgb(15, 255, 255)
rgb(15, 255, 252)
rgb(15, 255, 249)
```

**php**

```
$str = file_get_contents('colors.txt');
$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);
$ht = '';
foreach($arr as $el){
    $ht .= "<div class='color' style='background:" . $el . "'></div>\n";
}
echo $ht; // nothing visible on page
```

also tried

```
$arr = explode('\n', $str);
$arr = explode('\n\r', $str);
$arr = explode('\r\n', $str);
$arr = explode('LF', $str); // LF stands in notepad++
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you able to actually open the file? If you just var_dump ($str) do you get the correct data?

Comment: @ikyuchukov, yes, echoing entire $str works

Comment: @qadenza Your code is working. You are unable  to see anything on screen, because height and width of divs are not mentioned. Put some css for height and width..

`<style type="text/css">
    .color{
        width: 500px;
        height:20px;
    }
</style>`

Comment: @RakeshShukla It is not, PHP_EOL is system specific and if the file is not using the EOL of the system the PHP is running on, it will not correctly parse the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function:

```
$str = file('colors.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$ht = '';
foreach($str as $el){
    $ht .= "<div class='color' style='background:" . $el . "'></div>\n";
}
echo $ht;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use this:

```
preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $str);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are correctly outputting the file,I think this is a duplicate.

EOL is system specific and if the file was no correctly made on the system running PHP, it will not work.

You can check for the correct answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3997367/3244389