# Find a keyword, then display each line until it finds the next keyword in PHP

Tags: php, text-extraction, text-parsing, sql-parser, line-by-line

What I want to do is:

1. Open a sql file
2. Find a keyword then display the line
3. Keep displaying each line until the next keyword
4. Keep doing 1 - 3 until the end of the file

This is my code but it stops displaying after the first match:

```
<?php
$filename = 'test.sql';
$startWord = ':begin';
$endWord = 'sqlexception';

// Open the SQL file for reading
$file = fopen($filename, 'r');

if ($file) {
    $foundStart = false;

    while (!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgets($file);

        if ($foundStart || stripos($line, $startWord) !== false) {
            $foundStart = true;
            echo $line; // Display the current line

            if (stripos($line, $endWord) !== false) {
                $foundStart = false; // Stop displaying lines after finding the end word
            }
        }
    }

    fclose($file);
} else {
    echo "Unable to open the file.";
}
?>
```

This is the sql file I want to retrieve the data from

```
getDataNlp:begin


    declare continue handler for sqlexception 
    begin
        set returnCode = -1;
        set returnMsg = 'SQL Exception';
    end;
    
    if useTransaction = 1 then
        start transaction;
    end if;
    
    set returnMsg = '';
    set returnCode = 0;
    set @count = 0;
    set @orgName = orgName;
    set @orgId = '';
    set @oprEmail = oprEmail;

CreateOpr:BEGIN


    DECLARE idx INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE v_orgName VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT '';
    declare continue handler for sqlexception 
    begin
        set returnCode = -1;
        set returnMsg = 'SQL Exception';
    end;
    start transaction;

    set returnCode = 0;
    set returnMsg = '';
    set @count = 0;
    set @oprName = oprName;
            
    select count(1) into @count from Opr where name = @oprName;
    if (@count > 0) then
        set returnCode = -1;
        set returnMsg = 'Opr with same oprName already exist';
        rollback;
        leave CreateOpr;
    end if;
 
END ;;
```

And I want to retrieve the lines like this

```
getDataNlp: begin

    declare continue handler for sqlexception
```

Comment: Can you provide sample file you are working with? Logic looks correct, https://3v4l.org/EO7Qn, assuming file has multiple references to term

Comment: How do you know if a word is a keyword or not?

Comment: @user3783243 I added sample sql data in the question

Comment: Please do not yatta-yatta the sample data in your [mcve]. Provide significantly challenging input and your exact desired output so that answers can judged consistently and accurately.

Comment: @mickmackusa Sorry for shortening the sql code, I added a block of code and hope it gives you an idea. I just want to retrieve the 2 lines in my question and I didn't think shortening the code is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code stops displaying after the first match is because you're setting `$foundStart` back to false after you find the `$endWord`. Since you're reading the file line by line, `$foundStart` becomes false and it stops displaying any subsequent lines.

Check this `while` instead of yours:

```
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);

    if (stripos($line, $startWord) !== false) {
        $foundStart = true; 
    }

    if ($foundStart) {
        echo $line . '<br>'; 
    }

    if (stripos($line, $endWord) !== false && $foundStart) {
        echo "---- End of Block ----<br>"; 
        $foundStart = false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: undefined $foundStart.  Did you test your code before posting?

Comment: Thank you, it's working but is it possible to add something like "if $endWord is not found for the next 5 lines, skip and look for $startWord"?

Comment: Please clarify your question to contain a sufficiently challenging input which demonstrates known troublemaking scenarios and show your exact desired result @cod

Comment: @mickmackusa in online php editor is not working in VSCode with file works flawlessly if You downwoted me for that resason so it's not fair.
codename_zoe if i understand well you want to add a counter to keep track of the number of lines read after finding $startWord and before encountering $endWord. If the counter reaches a certain limit, say 5 lines, you want reset $foundStart to false and continue looking for the next $startWord?

Comment: @adek- Thank you. I added a counter and now it 's working fine

Comment: I did not dv this answer, but I can see that it has been neutralized.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just parse the whole sql file in one go with `preg_match_all()` instead of trying to parse line by line.

Use a ranged quantifier `{0,$yourLimit}` to declare how many lines are permitted between found start & end keywords.

A `.` will match all non-vertical space characters. I am assuming that you don't need multibyte support, but `u` can be added to the pattern modifiers.  `i` is for case-insensitivity.  `m` makes the `$` match the end of a line instead of the end of the string. `\R` matches newline sequences.  I am using a lookahead at the end to rtrim() the whitespaces that I assume you don't want in the result.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BFtfN))

```
$startWord = ':begin';
$endWord = 'sqlexception';
$maxLinesBetween = 4;
preg_match_all('#.*' . preg_quote($startWord) . '.*(?:\R.*){0,' . $maxLinesBetween . '}.*' . preg_quote($endWord) . '.*?(?=\s*$)#im', $sql, $m);
var_export($m[0]);
```

Comment: Hmm, haven't seen/used `\R` before. How does that differ from `\v`?

Comment: I tried this code but it returns this error:  "Deprecated: preg_match_all(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($subject) of type string is deprecated"

Comment: @cod Where I have `$sql`, you will need to access the file contents (`file_get_contents()`).  Regarding `\v` versus `\R`, `\v` will match a single vertical line character (such as `\r` or `\n`. `\R` matches a new line seqence -- `\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n`.  Here is a good demonstration of `\R` https://stackoverflow.com/a/63922758/2943403